# Bash variable echoing 0

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to create a simple bash script but I can't get the variable handling right. When the RESULT variable receives an empty value it does not echo "-1", it returns a 0. Why does bash turn the empty value into 0?

```
SERVICE="$1"
RESULT=`ps auxw | grep ${SERVICE} | grep -v grep | awk '{s+=$3} END {print s}'`
if [ -z "$RESULT" ]; then
   echo "-1"
else
   echo $RESULT
fi
```

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x` or `set -x` and see what's happening.

Comment: I tried your script and it works, what is the issue?

Comment: This would be better handled using `pgrep`.

Comment: There's really never a need to use the pattern `V=$(some cmd); if test -z "$V" ...`.  In your case, just do: `ps auxw | ... | grep -q . || echo -1`.  That is, let the command write its output to `grep -q .` . If no output is generated, echo -1. You might want to consider not using `ps auxw` here, and you might consider writing that -1 to stderr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is always a ${RESULT}. You see, you put the ${SERVICE} in the command line when you search for it so its always found. See how can we avoid it:

```
cat search.sh

SERVICE="$1"
RESULT=$(ps auxw | grep ${SERVICE} | grep -v 'grep\|search.sh' | awk '{s+=$3} END {print s}')
if [ -z "$RESULT" ]; then
   echo "-1"
else
   echo $RESULT
fi
```

I added the name of the script into the `grep -v`. Otherwise there is always a process called `search.sh ${SERVICE}`

However it is far from best practice. As I understand, you need the current CPU usage of the process by name? Consider the following:

```
SERVICE="$1"
RESULT=`pgrep ${SERVICE}`
if [ -z "$RESULT" ]; then
   echo "-1"
else
   for proc in ${RESULT}; do ps -p ${proc} -o %cpu | tail -n +2; done
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This script works as expected :)